# Antd UI library. Overriding <Table /> behavior on empty data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to render some other content if `<Table />` receives empty data Array. 
Currently its just showing `'No data'`, but I want to put some custom component there.

[image: Current default behavior on empty data property]

How this may be done?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a property of table, `locale`. This is an `object`, used to `define` following things:

`filterConfirm`, `filterReset`, `emptyText`.

Use `emptyText` to specify the `text` that you want to show if `data` is `empty`. Like this:

```
let locale = {
  emptyText: 'Abc',
};

<Table locale={locale}  dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />
```

Check the Doc: https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: I thought it only changed the text message, but indeed it does replace the icon as well.

Answer (score 30):

There is another way to do this, without touching the `locale` property:

Wrap the `<Table />` with a `<ConfigProvider />` and set the `renderEmpty` property:

```
<ConfigProvider renderEmpty={() => <Empty description="Custom message"/>}>
  <Table />
</ConfigProvider>
```

The `renderEmpty` function can return any component you want.

More details here: https://ant.design/components/config-provider/#API
Example from docs: https://ant.design/components/empty/#components-empty-demo-config-provider

Answer (score 19):

You can use `locale` props of antd table which is `Object`.
Instead of just passing `string` to `emptyText` you can pass `HTML` tag.

```
let locale = {
  emptyText: (
    <span>
      <p>
        <Icon type="like" />
        Custom Message
      </p>
      <Button>Custom Button</Button>
    </span>
  )
};

<Table locale={locale}  dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Locale can be used. Empty text can be given directly.

```
<Table 
   locale={{emptyText:"No data"} 
   dataSource={dataSource}
   columns={columns} />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is well explained on ant design site. Here is the link https://ant.design/components/empty/

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example, which uses `<Result/>` component of antd

App.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, Table, Result } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      key: "address"
    },
    {
      title: "Tags",
      key: "tags"
    }
  ];

  const data = [];

  let locale = {
    emptyText: (
      <Result
        title="No data"
        subTitle="No users have been created yet, Click on add button to create a new user"
        extra={[
          <Button type="primary">Add user</Button>,
          <Button>Cancel</Button>
        ]}
      />
    )
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table locale={locale} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Table
    className='myTasksTable'
    columns={TaskColumns}
    dataSource={myTasks}
    pagination={false}
    rowSelection={{
        type: selectionType,
        ...rowSelection,
    }}
    scroll={{ y: tableHeight }}
    locale={{
        emptyText: (
            <Empty
                image={Empty.PRESENTED_IMAGE_SIMPLE}
                description="No Tasks Available"
            />
        ),
    }}
/>
```

Something like this solution will change the description but while keeping the old icon so you don't have to put one from you own , or you like you can change it